# Is there a solution for the odd error of bitbake?

Tags: linux, git, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

When I used yocto to build my first linux system and after 'bitbake imx-image-multimedia' was excuted, I faced the odd error:

```
ERROR: gnu-config-native-20190501+gitAUTOINC+b98424c249-r0 do_unpack: Unpack failure for URL: 'git://git.savannah.gnu.org/config.git'. No up to date source found: clone directory not available or not up to date: /home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/downloads//git2/git.savannah.gnu.org.config.git; shallow clone not enabled
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20190501+gitAUTOINC+b98424c249-r0/temp/log.do_unpack.73483
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gnu-config/gnu-config_git.bb:do_unpack) failed with exit code '1'
```

Curious about the logfile, I opened `/home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20190501+gitAUTOINC+b98424c249-r0/temp/log.do_unpack.73483` and I see:

```
DEBUG: Executing python function do_unpack
DEBUG: Executing python function base_do_unpack
DEBUG: Running 'export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; unset _PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/0/vscode-ssh-auth-sock-7925763"; export PATH="/home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/sources/poky/scripts/native-intercept:/home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/sources/poky/scripts:/home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20190501+gitAUTOINC+b98424c249-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20190501+gitAUTOINC+b98424c249-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20190501+gitAUTOINC+b98424c249-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20190501+gitAUTOINC+b98424c249-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20190501+gitAUTOINC+b98424c249-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20190501+gitAUTOINC+b98424c249-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/sources/poky/bitbake/bin:/home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/build/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="/root"; git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 branch --contains b98424c249119b79d3f709e26eb86f2fd4d5e5f3 --list master 2> /dev/null | wc -l' in /home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/downloads//git2/git.savannah.gnu.org.config.git
ERROR: Unpack failure for URL: 'git://git.savannah.gnu.org/config.git'. No up to date source found: clone directory not available or not up to date: /home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/downloads//git2/git.savannah.gnu.org.config.git; shallow clone not enabled
DEBUG: Python function base_do_unpack finished
DEBUG: Python function do_unpack finished
```

What is 'ERROR: Unpack failure for URL: `git://git.savannah.gnu.org/config.git'. No up to date source found: clone directory not available or not up to date: /home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/downloads//git2/git.savannah.gnu.org.config.git; shallow clone not enabled` means?
What can I do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: The command is 'bitbake [target]', I mistakenly entered ‘it‘ before it.

Comment: Seems the clone didn't work as either the remote repo is not accessible by your build machine... or some fetch issue and unpack is failing.. could you do explicit fetch with `bitbake -f -c gnu-config -vv` and see what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

See first if this is similar to [this thread](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/UnpackError-while-building-gstreamer1-0-with-Yocto-Thud/m-p/980646)

> Currently, for my Yocto builds (for `nxp` and other boards) I used to share a same "downloads" `DL_DIR` to avoid unnecessary fetch operations.
>
> I tried to use an empty `DL_DIR...`and it worked fine.
>
> After investigating, I found out there is something wrecked in the "git2" sub-directory of `DL_DIR`.
> I don't know what exactly.
>
> So if you have a custom `DL_DIR` with a lot of stuff, try to rename your "`git2`" subdir as "`git2.bak`".

Check also if the `//` seen in `/home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/downloads//git2/git.savannah.gnu.org.config.git` means an empty environment variable, meaning check if there should be an intermediate folder between `downloads/` and `/git2`.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently encountered this problem. I had an empty do_fetch function

```
do_fetch(){
  :
}
```

. Just by removing it, the git repo was cloned properly.

Answer (score 0):

try normal clone with `git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/config.git /home/admin/Linux/Yocto/fsl/downloads//git2/git.savannah.gnu.org.config.git`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a terrible answer and should be removed. How was he supposed to try a normal clone when he clearly states he is using bitbake? Is he supposed to implement his own fetcher in Yocto?